# How does work if / else?

Tags: php, if-statement

I have `$first` and `$second`. They can have value `0` or `1`.

```
if ( $first AND $second ) {
   // True
} else {
   // False
}
```

My mind (and Google search) tells me, that the result is **true** only when `$first == 1` and `$second == 0` or vice versa. But the result is **true** when both of this variables are `1`.

I don't understand how does it works.

Comment: "AND" (&&) checks if both **$first** and **$second** evaluate to true (which is equal to 1) and "OR" (||) checks if either **$first** or **$second** evaluates to true.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your Google searches have failed you. PHP's [type juggling](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php) means that a `1` is equivalent to `TRUE` and `0` is equivalent to `FALSE`. (See also [type comparisons](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php)). So if both values are `1` then that if statement evaluates to `TRUE`. If one or both values are `0`, it evaluates to `FALSE`.

```
<?php

$one = 1;
$zero = 0;

if ($one && $one) {
    echo "true\n";
}
else {
    echo "false\n";
}

if ($zero && $zero) {
    echo "true\n";
}
else {
    echo "false\n";
}

if ($one && $zero) {
    echo "true\n";
}
else {
    echo "false\n";
}

if ($zero && $one) {
    echo "true\n";
}
else {
    echo "false\n";
}
```

Program Output

```
true
false
false
false
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/473704)

Comment: *"Your Google searches have failed you."* - Love that line ;-)

Comment: _The Google-Fu is weak in this one_

Answer (score 1):

In PHP all values are either "truthy" or "falsy" in expressions.

If a value *contains something* then it can be said to be truthy. So, values such as `1`, `"one"`, `[1,2,3]` or `true` all "contain" something and will be interpreted as truthy.

Values that are zeroed or in some way empty are falsy. E.g. `0`, `""`, `[]` and `false`.

There is a [table of how values are interpreted](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php) in the PHP documentation.

You can also just experiment, and output it to your website:

```
var_dump(1 and 0);
```